# what does ArrayList<Number> mean?

Tags: java, list, arraylist

Here's my current situation:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

import com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.NextAction;

import static java.lang.System.*;

public class NumberAnalyzer
{
private ArrayList<Number> list;

public NumberAnalyzer()
{

}

public NumberAnalyzer(String numbers)
{
    String nums = numbers;
    Scanner chopper = new Scanner(nums);
    while(chopper.hasNext()){
        int num = chopper.nextInt();
        list.add(num);
    }
    list = 
}
```

How would I go about converting a string of numbers, say `5 12 9 6 1 4 8 6`, and add them to this `ArrayList<Number>` that I have? Eclipse is stating that

> The method add(int, Number) in the type ArrayList is not applicable for the arguments (int).

**EDIT**
here are pastebin links to all the associated .java files:

http://pastebin.com/9KDXLwbL   (NumberAnalyzer.java)

http://pastebin.com/BGRpbpyH    (Number.java)

http://pastebin.com/EhmZ6kKH    (runner class)

http://pastebin.com/BCzeZytg    (NumberTester.java this one works well with Number.java, which was part one of the lab)

Comment: If it helps in knowing what number is, there is another .java file named Number.java that is somehow associated with this file.....

Comment: That would explain things.  Don't make a class called `Number`; `java.lang.Number` already exists.

Comment: I didn't name it, it was already named Number.java from the start for this lab.....

Comment: Get rid of it. Any course which gives you a class named `Number` is probably not worth taking.

Comment: Your `public Number() { }` constructor is very wrong.

Comment: I added another pastebin link with NumberTester.java, which could clarify the `public Number() {}` issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have another class `Number`.
Change your code this way:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NumberAnalyzer {

    private ArrayList<Number> list;

    public NumberAnalyzer() {
    }

    public NumberAnalyzer(String numbers) {
        list = new ArrayList<Number>();
        String nums = numbers;
        Scanner chopper = new Scanner(nums);
        while (chopper.hasNext()) {
            list.add(new Number(chopper.nextInt()));
        }
        chopper.close();
    }

}
```

In this way you are using you class `Number`, and not the default one.

Comment: ah.... that may just be the key to it....  I think someone else mentioned doing it similar to that earlier but not exactly... and my ArrayList wasn't initialized

Comment: Yes, it's what SLaks said. In my original answer I didn't see the rest of your code (that's why I edited it).
Also, remember to inizialize the list and to close the scanner.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, you have your own `Number` class in the current package.

Thus, your `ArrayList<Number>` doesn't contain `java.lang.Number`, but another type entirely. Therefore, you can't add an `int` to it; the compiler cannot convert an `int` into an instance of the custom `Number` class.

Instead, you need to explicitly create an instance of your `Number` class, or get rid of it and use `java.lang.Number`.  (which `int` has an implicit conversion to)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Parametrized approach, use Integer as the parameter and while adding cast it to Integer.

```
private ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
list.add(Integer.valueOf(num));
```

If you do not want to use the Parametrized approach, simply add it to the list as an int.

```
private ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
list.add(Integer.parseInt(num));
```

Comment: This does not actually answer the question.  And, _don't do that_.